# Tabs visibility on Napili Theme based on profile

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, napili, visibility, user-profile

I have 2 profiles that are accessing customer community built on "Napili theme",
profile1:system admin
profile2:customer Community user
I have 4 custom tabs tab1,tab2,tab3,tabs4
I want only first 3 tabs to be visible for "customer community user"
and all 4 tabs visible to "system admin"
Keeping in mind that we are using "Napili template".

Comment: Hi @RaviSingh, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help), scroll through the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: In Napili why are you trying to use tabs? It would be preferable to use pages with page variations based on the profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Audiences and Page Variations for show the 4 tabs to admins and 3 for customers.

You can read more here:

[Page Variations and Audience Targeting for Pages and Groups](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Answer (score 0):

By tabs do you mean 'Navigation Menu Items', if the answer is yes, you can control only the menu items that are based on Salesforce objects i.e by removing access to the object on profile. If you are using any other navigation menu items based on pages / external object etc, I don't think it is possible to control it.